# Disk usage of a symbolic link

Tags: linux, filesystems, symbolic-link, disk-space

If I check the file size of a symbolic link by `stat()`, then it reports a nonzero file size equal to the link path string. But when I use `du` on the link, it reports a size of zero blocks.

Is there a simple explanation for this? Is it correct to interpret symbolic links as requiring no disk space? Where is the symbolic link information being stored?

Comment: You might find [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88426/22222) useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink#Storage_of_symbolic_links. Modern systems use what are called "fast symlinks". No blocks are allocated for the symlink. Instead, the symlink reference is stored in the inode itself, where a regular file stores the locations of the blocks that make it up. `du` only looks at how many blocks are allocated, and so may show 0. `stat` and `ls -l` are smart enough to report the length of the symlink based on the data stored in the inode.

Comment: But if I do `du -B1 my_file`, it still turns up as zero. Doesn't `-b` enable the `apparent-size` flag? Maybe I should be asking where the data is saved?

Comment: This turned out to be much more involved than I realized - I've edited my answer.